# How to set OnTouchListener for a list of Views?

Tags: android, textview

Please, I need help. I want to set the OnTouchListener for each view that I have in a table of view.
Here is my code:

```
for(TextView tv : getChoices()){
    ChoicesLayout.addView(tv);
}
```

The getChoices methode return an array of textViews. I want to set OnTouchListener for each TextView and then add it to the layout.
Can someone help me please!

I tried this:

```
for(TextView tv : getChoices()){
tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
                // Start dragging the item
                v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        }
    });
    ChoicesLayout.addView(tv);
}
```

but It doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried for setting an OnTouchListener?

Comment: Can you edit that into your question so others can see it clearly? It may get a few more eyes onto this to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any idea how are you implementing your list of texte views, but I guess it is in a ListView.

you can try by adding the OnTouch in your ImageAdapter.

this a little [tutorial](http://nimroddayan.wordpress.com/2013/01/01/hooking-ontouchlistener-event-to-android-listviews-item/) . I hope I helped